# Laravel Resource - Parents with Childrens Categories

Tags: php, laravel

I want to load my childrens categories in the parent with Laravel Resource.

**My json is like that :**

```
    "data": [
    {
        "id": 2,
        "slug": "child-categorie-0",
        "name": "Child Catégorie 0",
        "parent_id": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "slug": "child-categorie-1",
        "name": "Child Catégorie 1",
        "parent_id": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "slug": "parent-categorie-0",
        "name": "Parent Catégorie 0",
        "parent_id": null
    },
],
```

**I would like to be like that :**

```
    "data": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "slug": "parent-categorie-0",
        "name": "Parent Catégorie 0",
        "childrens": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "slug": "child-categorie-0",
                "name": "Child Catégorie 0",
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "slug": "child-categorie-1",
                "name": "Child Catégorie 1",
            }                
        ]

    }
],
```

**App\Http\Resources\Category.php**

```php
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'slug' => $this->slug,
        'name' => $this->name,
        'parent_id' => $this->parent_id
    ];
}
```

**Controller**

```php
$categories = Category::orderBy('name', 'asc')->get();
return new CategoryCollection($categories);
```

I'm new with Laravel Resource so if someone have a path for solving this problem, thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solve my problem !

I create a relationship in my Category Model.

```php
public function childrens()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Category', 'parent_id', 'id');
}
```

**In my Category Resource**

```php
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'slug' => $this->slug,
        'name' => $this->name,
        'childrens' => self::collection($this->whenLoaded('childrens'))  
    ];
}
```

**In my Controller**

```
$categories = Category::with('childrens')->parents()->orderBy('name','asc')->get();
```